Integrating Legendre Polynomials over half range using rodrigues formula
I want derive that
$$\int^1_0 P_{2l+1}(x)dx=-\frac{(2l)!}{2^{2l+1}(2l+1)!}\binom{2l+1}{l}(-1)^{2l+1-l}=\frac{(2l)!}{2^{2l+1}(2l+1)!}\binom{2l+1}{l}(-1)^{l}$$
I tried replacing $P_l(x)$ by Rodrigues  formula
$$\int^1_0P_l(x)\;dx=\frac{1}{2^ll!}\int^1_0\frac{d^l}{dx^l}(x^2-1)^ldx=\frac{1}{2^ll!}\;\frac{d^{l-1}}{dx^{l-1}}(x^2-1)^l\bigg|^{1}_{0}$$
where $l$ is odd, and using the binomial expansion
$$(x^2-1)^l=\sum^l_{m=0}\binom{l}{m}(-1)^{l-m}x^{2m}$$
but I don't know how to do next.
I would really appreciate any help in understanding this problem!

Doing the same procedure you did we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 P_{2\ell+1}(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\dfrac{1}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}\int_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2\ell+1}}{\mathrm dx^{2\ell+1}}(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2\ell}}{\mathrm dx^{2\ell}}(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}\right|_0^1
\end{aligned}$$
To compute
$$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2\ell}}{\mathrm dx^{2\ell}}(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}\right|_0^1$$
it is equivalent to substracting the $2\ell$th coefficient of $(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}$ around $x=1$ and around $x=0$. That is because if
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}a_k(x-x_0)^k,$$
then
$$a_k=\dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}\iff f^{(k)}(x_0)=k!a_k$$
Around $x=1$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}&=2^{2\ell+1}\left(1+\dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^{2\ell+1}(x-1)^{2\ell+1}\\
&=2^{2\ell+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2\ell+1}{2\ell+1\choose k}\left(\dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^k(x-1)^{2\ell+1},
\end{aligned}$$
and so, since the polynomial is of order $2\ell+1$ or higher, its $2\ell$th coefficient is $0$.
Now as for around $x=0$, we get
$$(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}=-(1-x^2)^{2\ell+1}=-\sum_{k=0}^{2\ell+1}{2\ell+1\choose k}(-1)^kx^{2k}$$
The $2\ell$th coefficient will then be
$$-\left.{2\ell+1\choose k}(-1)^k\right|_{k=\ell}=-{2\ell+1\choose \ell}(-1)^\ell$$
To sum up,
$$\begin{aligned}
\small\color{blue}{\int_0^1 P_{2\ell+1}(x)\,\mathrm dx}&=\dfrac{1}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2\ell}}{\mathrm dx^{2\ell}}(x^2-1)^{2\ell+1}\right|_0^1\\
&=\dfrac{(2\ell)!}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}\left[a_{2\ell}^{x_0=1}-a_{2\ell}^{x_0=0}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{(2\ell)!}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}\left[0-\left(-{2\ell+1\choose \ell}(-1)^\ell\right)\right]\\
&\color{blue}{=\dfrac{(-1)^\ell(2\ell)!}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}{2\ell+1\choose \ell}}
\end{aligned}
$$
As @BobDobbs mentioned,
$$\small\dfrac{(-1)^\ell(2\ell)!}{2^{2\ell+1}(2\ell+1)!}{2\ell+1\choose \ell}=\dfrac{(-1)^\ell(2\ell)!}{2^{2\ell+1}\ell!(\ell+1)!}=\dfrac{(-1)^\ell(2\ell-1)!!}{2^{\ell+1}(\ell+1)!}=(-1)^\ell\dfrac{(2\ell-1)!!}{(2\ell+2)!!}$$

The answer can be written as $(-1)^l\frac{(2l-1)!!}{(2l+2)!!}$.

Thank you very much! your answer is amazing! And can you recommend some textbooks or lectures on this subject?

I don't really read many textbooks... Maybe ask through another post.

But why for the $2l$th coefficient, that $k=l$ ?

Because you're searching for the coefficient accompanying $x^{2\ell}$. When we evaluate the $k=\ell$th term of the sum we get the term with power $x^{2\ell}$.

Starting from
$$(x^2-1)^l=\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2-1)^{l+1}}{2(l+1)(2l+1)}-\frac{2l}{2l+1}(x^2-1)^{l-1}$$
we get
$$\frac1{2^l l!}\frac{d^{l-1}}{dx^{l-1}}(x^2-1)^l=\frac{P_{l+1}(x)-P_{l-1}(x)}{2l+1}.$$
Can you continue from here? You need the values of the Legendre polynomials at $x=0$ and $x=1$. You may search for them from Wolfram MathWorld's Legendre polynomials page.
